# Convert a list of string to category integer in Python

Tags: python, categories

Given a list of string,

```
['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

I would like to convert to an integer-category form

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

This can achieve using numpy unique as below

```
ipt=['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b']
_, opt = np.unique(np.array(ipt), return_inverse=True)
```

But, I curious if there is another alternative without the need to import `numpy`.

Comment: Is your list of strings always single, alphabetical characters?

Comment: Yeah figured, otherwise was going to suggest what @pySam answered. You could just write your own unique function for that if you don't want to import numpy, unsure how efficient it would be though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are solely interested in finding integer representation of factors, then you can use a dict comprehension along with `enumerate` to store the mapping, after using `set` to find unique values:

```py
lst = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b']

d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(set(lst))}
lst_new = [d[x] for x in lst]
print(lst_new)

# [3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

This approach can be used for general factors, i.e., the factors do not have to be `'a'`, `'b'` and so on, but can be `'dog'`, `'bus'`, etc. One drawback is that it does not care about the order of factors. If you want the representation to preserve order, you can use `sorted`:

```py
d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(lst)))}
lst_new = [d[x] for x in lst]
print(lst_new)

# [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a note out of the functional programming book:

```py
ipt=['a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'b']
opt = list(map(lambda x: ord(x)-97, ipt))
```

This code iterates through the input array and passes each element through the lambda function, which takes the ascii value of the character, and subtracts 97 (to convert the characters to 0-25).
If each string isn't a single character, then the lambda function may need to be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom function to do the same thing as you are using `numpy.unique()` for.

```
def unique(my_list):
    ''' Takes a list and returns two lists, a list of each unique entry and the index of
    each unique entry in the original list
    '''
    unique_list = []
    int_cat = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(item)
        int_cat.append(unique_list.index(item))
    return unique_list, int_cat
```

Or if you wanted your indexing to be ordered.

```
def unique_ordered(my_list):
    ''' Takes a list and returns two lists, an ordered list of each unique entry and the
    index of each unique entry in the original list
    '''
    # Unique list
    unique_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(item)

    # Sorting unique list alphabetically
    unique_list.sort()

    # Integer category list
    int_cat = []
    for item in my_list:
        int_cat.append(unique_list.index(item))
    return unique_list, int_cat
```

Comparing the computation time for these two vs `numpy.unique()` for 100,000 iterations of your example list, we get:

```
numpy = 2.236004s
unique = 0.460719s
unique_ordered = 0.505591s
```

Showing that either option would be faster than numpty for simple lists. More complicated strings decrease the speed of `unique()` and `unique_ordered` much more than `numpy.unique()`. Doing 10,000 iterations of a random, 100 element list of 20 character strings, we get times of:

```
numpy = 0.45465s
unique = 1.56963s
unique_ordered = 1.59445s
```

So if efficiency was important and your list had more complex/a larger variety of strings, it would likely be better to use `numpy.unique()`